# Internet Explorer WebView UI Automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, wxwidgets, ui-automation, iwebbrowser2

I have a Win32 C++ application using wxWidgets. I have `wxWebviewCtrl` (assuming it is using Windows [IWebBrowser2 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/exdisp/nn-exdisp-iwebbrowser2)).

The requirement is to have UI automation support for IE based `Webview` by automation tools like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or similar.

I understand these UI automation tools work fine with Internet Explorer. I have no idea how can I use these tools for IE Webview.

Comment: which version of wxWidgets you use? Which Windows version?

Comment: I am using wxWidgets3.1, Win7, 8, 8.1, 10